# Insert parent child record with Mulesoft

Tags: mulesoft

I am new to Mulesoft and using Mule4-Salesforce connector, I am trying to insert contact with Account but I am not sure how to do it, any help/documentation is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Salesforce Composite Connector (will not be available in the Mule palette initially. To get these connectors, search in the Mule palette exchange.).

Now create configuration for sObject tree connector which requires below properties:

1. **Consumer Key and Consumer secret:**
   For Consumer key and secret, you need to create a connected app in Salesforce.

Go to Setup -> Build -> Create -> Apps -> Create new in Connected apps
2. **Username and Password:**
This should be set to the username and password of Salesforce Org where the app is created.
After this get back to Anypoint Studio and create a basic flow using the sObject tree connector:

[image]

Set payload with sObject tree:

[image]

When you run the application, in response, you will get the Salesforce IDs of newly created accounts and contacts.